# Inject BL to OAuth with AutoFac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, owin, autofac

I have followed this [Blog](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/refresh-token-in-web-api/) to Generate Refresh Token in my WebApi. In RefreshTokenProvider class he is accessing AuthenticationRepository to create a row in table for generated refresh token. Every thing works perfectly. But now I want to add dependency Injection to my WebAPI Project. For Dependency Injection I am using AutoFac with the following configurations

```
public class IocConfig
{
    public static AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterType<DefaultPrincipalProvider>().As<IPrincipalProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<Logic>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DataAccess>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<AuthRefreshTokenProvider>().As<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>().SingleInstance();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    IocConfig.Configure();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
    private Logic _logic;
    public ItemController(Logic logic)
    {
        _logic = logic;
    }
}
```

**Business Logic**

```
public partial class Logic
{
    IPrincipalProvider _principalProvider;
    DataAccess _dataAccess;
    string _currentUserId;

    public Logic(DataAccess dataAccess,IPrincipalProvider provider)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

}
```

**DataAccess**

```
public partial class DataAccess
{

    public DataAccess()
    {
    }

}
```

Every thing works fine with the above configuration but I am stuck on how to configure `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`. I need to pass `BusinessLogic` Instance to AuthRefreshTokenProvider.

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthRefreshTokenProvider(),// Need To use Dependency Injection Here
    // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

**AuthRefreshTokenProvider**

```
public class AuthRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    private Logic _logic;
    public AuthRefreshTokenProvider(Logic logic)
    {
        _logic = logic;
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of ways to make this work. I know the problem is in Instantiating `InstancePerRequest()` inside SingleInstance. I have been reading a lot of articles and stackoverflow posts to get this working but cant seem to make it work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your question is about accessing scoped services from a singleton service context?

Assuming your application is ASP.Net WebAPI (not Core), you need to capture the `HttpRequestMessage` in order to have access to the request scope.

First, you need somewhere to keep the request message, and because you want to access the request message from singleton service, the new service also needs to be a **singleton** service:

```
interface IHttpRequestAccessor
{
    HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
}

class HttpRequestAccessor : IHttpRequestAccessor
{
    private readonly AsyncLocal<HttpRequestMessageHolder> _currentRequest =
        new AsyncLocal<HttpRequestMessageHolder>();

    public HttpRequestMessage Request
    {
        get => _currentRequest.Value?.Value;
        set
        {
            HttpRequestMessageHolder holder = _currentRequest.Value;
            if (holder != null)
            {
                holder.Value = null;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                _currentRequest.Value = new HttpRequestMessageHolder { Value = value };
            }
        }
    }

    private class HttpRequestMessageHolder
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Value { get; set; }
    }
}

builder.RegisterType<HttpRequestAccessor>()
    .As<IHttpRequestAccessor>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

**How this works?**

This class exposes a property to get and set `HttpRequestMessage` to the current async execution context. Because the data context is different for each request and is inherited in all steps in the WebAPI request pipeline, we could set it in one place and later use it in another place for the same HTTP request. This is the same concept how `IHttpContextAccessor` is done in ASP.Net Core apps.

Now we need somewhere to capture and set `IHttpRequestAccessor.Request`. A [delegating handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) is a good option:

```
class CaptureHttpRequestMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpRequestAccessor _requestMessageAccessor;

    public CaptureHttpRequestMessageHandler(IHttpRequestAccessor requestMessageAccessor)
    {
        _requestMessageAccessor = requestMessageAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_requestMessageAccessor != null)
        {
            _requestMessageAccessor.Request = request;
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And add it to the configuration:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(
    new CaptureHttpRequestMessageHandler(/* resolve services here */));
```

After all, inject `IHttpRequestAccessor` to your `AuthRefreshTokenProvider` and remove `Logic`.

Whenever `Logic` is needed, resolve it on the fly using:

```
_httpRequestAccessor.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(Logic));
```

As long as the `AuthRefreshTokenProvider` is called when **there is** an HTTP request, this should work.